# Is there a better way to remove a repeated element based on its occurrence?

Tags: python, function

I created a python function namely 'oremove(l, n, o)'. Basically what it does is to remove an element 'n' in list 'l' whose occurrence is 'o'. For example; l = [1, 3, 4, 5, 3], n = 3 and o = 2, gives an output [1, 3, 4, 5] as it removed the second '3' from the list. My code is as follows:

```
# Here l = list, n = number, o = occurrence.
def oremove(l, n, o):
    count = 0
    t = 0
    for i in l:
        if i == n:
            count += 1
            if count == o:
                del l[t]
                return l
            else:
                t += 1
        else:
            t += 1
    else:
        return l
```

My question is that; is there a better way to achieve the same result by tweaking the code or is there an inbuilt function in python ?

Comment: This is certainly some sort of course work, right? If we gave you the super compact Python answer, that would surely stick out as too advanced, wouldn't it?

Comment: In particular, [austins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56721966/1324033) is essentially what you're looking for

Comment: @deceze I swear this isn't a part of our coursework.

Comment: @Sayse this does it for me, thank you!